# How to subtract amount from same list in linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

How do I subtract the `Amount` if the `Id` and `FreeUpOriginId` matches in my query? I could achieve my desired result bu using `foreach` but I was wondering if it can be done in one select query.

```
DateTime DateToday = DateTime.Now;
var availed = (from c in db.Allocations
               where c.Status == Status.Availed && c.FiscalYear == DateToday.Year
               select c).ToList();
var freeup = (from c in db.Allocations
              where c.Status == Status.FreeUp && c.FiscalYear == DateToday.Year
              select c).ToList();
foreach (var availedItem in availed)
{
    foreach (var freeupItem in freeup)
    {
        if (availedItem.Id == freeupItem.FreeUpOriginId)
        {
            availedItem.Amount = availedItem.Amount - freeupItem.Amount;
        }
    }
}
return new JsonNetResult() { Data = availed };
```

Comment: LINQ is a query language. It doesn't let you update properties within a query. You have to either create new objects (as per Barr J's answer) or you need to eventually do the equivalent of `foreach`. Generally the `foreach` is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is an easiest one, this is the basic snippet to point you in your direction:

```
var Result = availed.Select(x => new Data()
{
    //your properties
    Amount = x.Amount - freeupItem.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.Id)?.Amount ?? 0
}).ToList();
```

Comment: would this be a new query aside from my availed and freeup query?

Comment: then I will have three queries, I wanted to ask how to create just one query but with my desired results.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a query language. It doesn't let you update properties within a query. You have to either create new objects (as per Barr J's answer) or you need to eventually do the equivalent of `foreach`. Generally the `foreach` is more readable.

Try this:

```
var allocs = db.Allocations.Where(x => x.FiscalYear == DateToday.Year);

var query =
    from avail in allocs.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Availed)
    join free in allocs.Where(x => x.Status == Status.FreeUp)
        on avail.Id equals free.FreeUpOriginId
    select new { avail, free };

query.ToList().ForEach(x => x.avail.Amount -= x.free.Amount);
```

The last like can be written as:

```
foreach (var x in query)
{
    x.avail.Amount -= x.free.Amount;
}
```

Comment: It returns two results.

Comment: @klent - What do you mean?

Comment: I get the error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." so I added a ToList() to the select new to get rid of it now the the query return two results 'free' and 'avail' after the foreach.

Comment: @klent - A `foreach` doesn't return anything. I'm struggling to understand what you mean?

Comment: query is returning two results (arrays), avail and free.

Comment: @klent - No, it's not. It's returning a single `IEnumerable<T>` (not an array) with the `T` being an anonymous type containing two properties `avail` and `free`. It has to do that so that the assignment can be made in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I removed the ToList() I added to the Select new so it returning the error below again: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: @klent - Sorry, I don't know what you mean or indeed what you're trying to say?